# SQLServer Windows Authentification through Tomcat

Tags: java, sql-server, windows, tomcat, jdbc

I have an application developed in MS Access, and I'm currently switching it to a web application with Apache Tomcat.

The Access application has our SQL Server database fully linked, so it has entire control of the data.

The application is running a hidden process by passing the ActiveDirectory authentication to the SQL Server, so the users never type their passwords.

But from Tomcat, I tried to connect on the SQL Server using JDBC driver and Windows authentication (`jdbc:sqlserver://SERVERADDRESS;integratedSecurity=true;`) in just one `jsp` file to test the database connection.

The problem here is instead of passing the user login which launched the app through his web browser, it passes the Server identifier (Which is `DOMAIN\SERVERNAME`).

Can I get the username with this way, or do I need to completely change my connection system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible without credential delegation/S4U services for Kerberos. Especially, if you don't use Java's Kerberos implementation, but the one from Windows SSPI.

Start your users to authenticate via [SPNEGO](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj3vujg0ODRAhXLJSwKHaRYDMoQFgg-MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net%2F&usg=AFQjCNFNGGj9YDjvyNP3Q8tyJC7Tqp3DDw&sig2=MsSGCvSugS2YgjR7LChDag) first, then come back.

Comment: Does Kerberos is fully transparent ? I mean, the users wouldn't have to do anything in addition ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Everything is configured at Active Directory level and your code. Zero conf for your clients. IE enables delegation by default. Firefox is a little switch.

Comment: Thanks for your help !